# Remove selected punctuation from list of sentences

Tags: python, list, nltk, punctuation

I have a list of sentences like :
[' no , 2nd main 4th a cross, uas layout, near ganesha temple/ bsnl exchange, sanjaynagar, bangalore',
 ' grihalakshmi apartments flat , southend road basavangudi bangalore -560004. opp adiyar ananda bhavan near south end c',
 ' srinivas pg acomudation ;opp to cosmos mall brooke field',
 ' royal palms 2nd cross,l b sastry nagar bangalore',
 ' bmp ho name grija \krishnappa garden bagamane .technologi park cv ramanagar']

i need to remove all punctuation except for , and / .. i used string.punctuation to remove all

```
def punc(x):
    predicate = lambda y:y not in string.punctuation
    out = filter(predicate,x)
    return out
data = data.apply(punc)
```

this removed everything.. want to remove selected ones..plz help

i used .apply() for it when it was part of a dataframe. now i've converted it to a list. so please reccommend a technique to deal with exceptional punctuations in a list object.

Comment: Is that want to remove or replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def punc(x):
    predicate = lambda y:y not in ''.join(c for c in string.punctuation if c not in ',/')
    out = filter(predicate,x)
    return out
```

Besides, apply() is deprecated.

Remove when prepositions are in the string.

```
def punc(x):
    predicate = lambda y:y not in ''.join(c for c in string.punctuation if c not in './')
    prepositions = ['a', 'in']  #define by yourself
    if any(p in x.split() for p in prepositions):
        return filter(predicate,x)
    return x
```

Comment: thanks.. what if i add some conditions.. like remove punctuations only when prepositions are present??